# (React) Ag grid: load column state from local storage without actively showing the columns moving

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid

I want to be able to load the column state from the local storage, and apply it to the grid on page load.
As of now I use a set of event listeners to save that state in the local storage.
I utilise the "OnGridReady" prop to apply these event listeners and to recover the state from the local storage.

The main problem is that the grid will start in the "default-layout" and then switch to the local storage state couple of ms afterwards.

Is there a way to load the local-storage column state before the grid is rendered with the default state?

Comment: Have you tried performing this before the browser repaints by using useLayoutEffect hook to set the rowData?

Comment: Can't you just show the grid when the data from local storage are loaded? You know - {data && <Grid... } I do not know ag-grid but at the end you can mount it but hide by css and when data is loaded, show it back

Comment: Loading the grid after the data is loaded doesn't change the result, as I need to interact with gridApi to change the column state, and that is not ready until the "OnGridReady" event is fired.  At the same time I cannot use the useLayoutEffect since I need the gridApi to be able to utilise the setColumnState function on the Api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you 'hide' the grid, but still have the onGridReady event fired by setting a div containing the grid (or maybe the grid itself) to "visibility:hidden" in css, rather than using *ngIf or setting it to "display:none".

So, start with the grid hidden, load and apply the grid state, and then "unhide" it.

Comment: Works well enough to do it this way. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: But then the grid will appear at the *beginning* of the transtition between the default column state and the restored column state. This will not hide the column animation.